# SharePoint How To Get a ViewName

Tags: sharepoint

I need to get data from SharePoint by using web service. I did it, but i don't know how to get data from View.

```
XmlNode itemNode = spList.GetListItems(url[1], 
                                       null, 
                                       ndQuery, 
                                       ndViewFields, 
                                       null, 
                                       ndQueryOptions, 
                                       null);
```

Second parameter must be ViewName.

I have found `System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = spList.GetListAndView(url[1], "");` but it return default ViewName ("AllItems") guid. There's more than two views.

Is any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved the problem. I have used List web service but there's another View. So I looked it and found the method i need GetViewCollection, as i remember.
That's all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetList method, which returns a Caml List Schema and from which you can extract a description of all view.
[GetList method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx)